# jQuery / CSS 3 animation - Conceptual solution - moving down a road into the horizon

Tags: jquery, css, animation, 3d

Just to be clear from the start - what I'm looking for is a **conceptual solution/approach not working code**.

### The problem

I've been asked to look into a navigation of a timeline - where you walk down a road into the horizon.

The inspiration image looks like this:

[image: Inspiration image]

The general idea is that each yellow/red line defines a place in time, when you click on it, you should walk down the the road into that place of time.

The actual graphics will probably be a lot different.

### My idea/approach so far

I was thinking about how to create such an animation. I thought about cutting the picture into 4 regions, the horizon, the road and the two sides.

By keeping the horizon still, moving the two sides in the direction of the road and moving the road straight down while making it wider, I think the animation of moving could be possible. See pic:

[image: Explaination]

This is a pretty simple approach, but I do see some problems with it, like how to add details to the graphic when moving down. This could probably be solved by replacing the images along the way, which would be very easy to see when you move far down the road in one go.

### Please help

What I'm looking for - is a conceptual way of doing something like this, not the actual solution. Code snippets would be great too.

- Do I have a sane approach?
- Can this be done in a smarter way?
- Am I missing something obvious?
- Any good tools that can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a off the cuff idea! Why not animate a .gif of the road moving that will run through when you click on it, after the animation runs through you could update the road and sides with the new information that should be displayed depending on where you clicked on the road? This would be more of a javascripted approach. I don't know how you could go about moving Images in that way with CSS.

I think if this was done quickly it would looks pretty smooth, the effect would kindof be like the road view of Google maps when you move to a new area. It would run through a movement animation and then update surroundings.

Comment: +1 for a very simple idea - not sure if I'll use it but I like your way of thinking.

Comment: Appreciate it. *Extra Characters*

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could go about this.

> Please help
>
> What I'm looking for - is a conceptual way of doing something like
>   this, not the actual solution. Code snippets would be great too.
>
> - Do I have a sane approach?
> - Can this be done in a smarter way?
> - Am I missing something obvious?
> - Any good tools that can help me with this?

1. It is a sane approach but can be very time consuming and involve a lot of testing
2. It could be done with the use of [`CSS animations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) with a mix of scripting. You also could bust out the [`HTML5 canvas`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) and use that method.
3. Your not missing anything obvious but it will be an interesting challenge.
4. Refer to number 2 for some options. Also you can dig through the code on the website below to try and figure out how they accomplished it. Here is another great tutorial on using [sprites to make animations](http://simurai.com/blog/2012/12/03/steps-animation/). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/) by: simurai.

**This [website should be](http://www.exsus.com/highway-one-roadtrip/) a huge inspiration to you and show that it is possible.**

In this website a lot of the animations are done with `CSS keyframes`.

Comment: No problem! I'm sure your not trying to make a site that involved but it should give you some great ideas and something to ogle at. :] Best of luck in your creation and hopefully it is a successful one!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with CSS3 3D transforms.

Most of the rendering problems (generate the perspective, allow for the movement, keep the posibility to respond to mouse events) can be solved , if not easily, without too many problems.

Does the text "adding details as the graphic moves down" mean that you plan to have some kind of delayed loading. Than can be difficult ...  and most of the people don't do it. If  it's just a matter of hidding details, I would leave that to the rendering engine.

In this regard, this web can be worth looking at:

[infinite zoom](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/test/css3/)